# Strange NoSuchBeanDefinitionException in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I get a classic org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Server': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private MyClass Server.myClass; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [MyClass] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at root.package.Application.main(Application.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private MyClass Server.myClass; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [MyClass] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [MyClass] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 14 more
```

"MyClass" in the stack trace above is of course the FQN of my class, which I replaced in this case (I can't show my package). It's a simple Netty Handler:

```
@Service
public class MyClass extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Protocol> implements Visitor {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, Protocol protocol) throws Exception {
        channelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(protocol.accept(this, channelHandlerContext));
    }

    public Object visit(Protocol protocol, ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext) {
        return restTemplate.exchange(...);
    }
}
```

The class that depends on MyClass:

```
@Component
public class Server {
    @Autowired
    private MyClass myClass;

    private ChannelFuture serverChannelFuture;

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() throws Exception {
        serverChannelFuture = bootstrap().bind(tcpPort()).sync();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        serverChannelFuture.channel().close();
        serverChannelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    }

    private ServerBootstrap bootstrap() {
        // Bootstrap setup
    }
}
```

And my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("root.package")
public class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    public Logger logger() {
        return Logger.getLogger(InternalLoggerFactory.class.toString());
    }
}
```

All my classes are in either root.package or a subpackage of it. MyClass is in a subpackage as well.

I have no idea why this would cause the above Exception. I have other Services in my root.package package that are being autowired just fine! Does any one have an idea?

EDIT: after some further testing, it appears the "visit" method is the problem. If I rename it, the application boots fine. Could this be a bug in Spring?

EDIT 2: I celebrated too early. I renamed the method in my Visitor interface and now I'm back to the same problem. Even if I comment out my interface, I cannot have any method with the same name as that interface. MyClass is the only class that implements Visitor that is a Spring bean.

Comment: Why dont you describe the `some autowired fields`. Secondly, post a little more of the stacktrace. Lastly, you have just given class name and there annotations, although useful, don't cover the entire picture. An edit seems in order.

Comment: I've added everything that might be relevant (I hope)

Comment: I've tried making all my classes Spring services. They are all injected as expected, but still not my MyClass. If I debug my application, I can see that the constructor of MyClass is being run. It's a total mystery for me

Comment: The logs state: 2016-03-29 11:42:12 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:484 - Finished creating instance of bean 'myClass'. But then a few lines further, the exception is thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer set me on my way: [Spring instantiates bean but can't use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385714/spring-instantiates-bean-but-cant-use-it)

The problem was that I use Spring aspects as well, which are configured with

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
```

However, by default, this enables JDK proxies, which work differently (see the answer of that question for more info).

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
```

Enables CGLIB proxies, which was the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your class MyClass has no package name?

```
"No qualifying bean of type [MyClass]"
```

in your Configuration you set the componentscan to a specififc package

```
@ComponentScan("root.package")
```

so Spring could not found your beans.

to fix: remove ("root.package") or add the package "root.package" to your classes

Comment: I replaced the FQN of my class with just the class name. MyClass is in root.package.*.MyClass. Sorry for the confusion, but I'm not able to show our package structure. I probably could have made that a bit more clear... Do you mean to try just @ComponentScan("")? I tried it, but no difference..

Comment: No luck. Other Services, Beans and Components work fine

Answer (score 0):

The thing about Spring annotations is that classes must reside in the same package tree as the runner or context.

For example, if your Spring application class is in `com.dippity.dot.myapp` all other classes annotated as `@Service`, `@Component`, etc must also be down the `com.dippity.dot.myapp` package tree.

A `@Service` annotated package could live `com.dippity.dot.myapp.service` and work.